# From below xml i have to read the property in javascript "wd:Descriptor"

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <wd:Get_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response wd:version="v34.0" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
         <wd:Request_Criteria>
            <wd:Employee_Reference wd:Descriptor="Sheila Xu （徐舒莘）">
               <wd:ID wd:type="WID">6f141c57519e4e14a2b7d1650ac39367</wd:ID>
               <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">21160</wd:ID>
            </wd:Employee_Reference>
         </wd:Request_Criteria>         
      </wd:Get_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Property to be read `wd:Descriptor`.

I tried with

```
/env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response/wd:Request_Criteria/wd:Employee_Reference/@wd:Descriptor
```

but it is coming as null. how do i access it?
I tried in xpath tester online it is giving me
Attribute='wd:Descriptor=Sheila Xu （徐舒莘）'

Comment: <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <wd:Get_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response wd:version="v34.0" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
         <wd:Request_Criteria>
            <wd:Employee_Reference wd:Descriptor="Sheila Xu （徐舒莘）">
               <wd:ID wd:type="WID">6f141c57519e4e14a2b7d1650ac39367</wd:ID>
               <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">21160</wd:ID>
            </wd:Employee_Reference>
         </wd:Request_Criteria>         
      </wd:Get_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in the browser you can do something like

```
const myXmlText = "...your xml string...";
const myXmlParser = new DomParser();
const myXmlDoc = myXmlParser.parseFromString(myXmlText, 'text/xml');

const myDescriptorElement = myXmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('wd:Employee_Reference')[0];
// Now you have a reference to the tag
const myDesiredValue = myDescriptorElement.getAttribute('wd:Descriptor');
```

This is what I was looking at, you could probably play around with this to get your values:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

To access `Employee_ID` you could use the following xpath expression:

```
/env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response/wd:Request_Criteria/wd:Employee_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Employee_ID"]/text()
```

[Demo](http://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable+all+extensions&data=%3Cenv%3AEnvelope+xmlns%3Aenv%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2Fsoap%2Fenvelope%2F%22%3E%0D%0A+++%3Cenv%3ABody%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Cwd%3AGet_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response+wd%3Aversion%3D%22v34.0%22+xmlns%3Awd%3D%22urn%3Acom.workday%2Fbsvc%22%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Cwd%3ARequest_Criteria%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++%3Cwd%3AEmployee_Reference+wd%3ADescriptor%3D%22Sheila+Xu+%EF%BC%88%E5%BE%90%E8%88%92%E8%8E%98%EF%BC%89%22%3E%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%3Cwd%3AID+wd%3Atype%3D%22WID%22%3E6f141c57519e4e14a2b7d1650ac39367%3C%2Fwd%3AID%3E%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%3Cwd%3AID+wd%3Atype%3D%22Employee_ID%22%3E21160%3C%2Fwd%3AID%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++%3C%2Fwd%3AEmployee_Reference%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3C%2Fwd%3ARequest_Criteria%3E+++++++++%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Fwd%3AGet_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response%3E%0D%0A+++%3C%2Fenv%3ABody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fenv%3AEnvelope%3E&extract=%2Fenv%3AEnvelope%2Fenv%3ABody%2Fwd%3AGet_Time_Off_Plan_Balances_Response%2Fwd%3ARequest_Criteria%2Fwd%3AEmployee_Reference%2Fwd%3AID[%40wd%3Atype%3D%22Employee_ID%22]%2Ftext()%0D%0A&extract-kind=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous)